# android loading a lot of bitmap cause the heap grow drastic

Tags: android, bitmap, heap-memory

Im building a news app that load many bitmap from url and display them on screen.
every time I load 20 pic`s and when user reach the bottom on the screen I load 20 more..
the problem is that every page (white 20 pics) takes about 15-20 mega of the heap memory, when I reach page 3 its already 60 mega +.
I read about loading bitmap from the android developer and did preaty much what they said but still faceing the large heap.

this is the code I call to load new bitmap:

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmap(String url, int width, int hight) {

    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedOutputStream out = null;
    int icWidth = width;
    int picHight = hight;

    try {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream(),
                IO_BUFFER_SIZE);

        final ByteArrayOutputStream dataStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(dataStream, IO_BUFFER_SIZE);
        copy(in, out);
        out.flush();

        final byte[] data = dataStream.toByteArray();
        bitmap = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(data, 0, width);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Could not load Bitmap from: " + url);
    } finally {
        closeStream(in);
        closeStream(out);
    }

    return bitmap;
}

public static void resycle() {
    bitmap.recycle();
}

/**
 * Closes the specified stream.
 * 
 * @param stream
 *            The stream to close.
 */
private static void closeStream(Closeable stream) {
    if (stream != null) {
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            android.util.Log.e(TAG, "Could not close stream", e);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Copy the content of the input stream into the output stream, using a
 * temporary byte array buffer whose size is defined by
 * {@link #IO_BUFFER_SIZE}.
 * 
 * @param in
 *            The input stream to copy from.
 * @param out
 *            The output stream to copy to.
 * @throws IOException
 *             If any error occurs during the copy.
 */
private static void copy(InputStream in, OutputStream out)
        throws IOException {
    byte[] b = new byte[IO_BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read;
    while ((read = in.read(b)) != -1) {
        out.write(b, 0, read);
    }
}

public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(byte[] data,
        int width, int hight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, width, hight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);

}

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
        // keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}
```

}

how can I load a lot of pics while maintaining small heap?

Comment: By scaling them down.

Comment: im allready do it...when I call the "loadBitmap" method I`m sending the bitmap url and the width and hight of the pic according to the users screen size..

Comment: Yup, you're right, my bad. So what is the final size that you end up with, typically?

Comment: again, it depends on the users screen size... I take the table width (little bit lees then the screen width) -20 for the width, the hight is (width-20)/1.5

Comment: That's why I added the "typically" to my question.

Comment: somewhere about 300X200 - 400X300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might have found two issues:

**1.** The following method

```
public static Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(byte[] data,
    int width, int hight)
```

takes a width and a height parameter, but you're calling it with

```
decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(data, 0, width);
```

So basically passing 0 as the requested width, and the width as the requested height. That doesn't seem right.

**2.** You mentioned that you're passing the full table width/height as the requested width/height for each image. You say that you're loading 20 per page, so shouldn't that be the size of a table cell instead of the full table?

Right now, you're at most scaling them down to the full screen size, which even on smaller devices will leave a big image.

Comment: hey, Ive add the correct width and height to the method.. thanks for pointing that out. Im passing only the table width as parameter, the height I cut from the width.. the width always stay the same so I dont think its a problem...

Comment: I think the more significant problem is that you're really not scaling down to a more thumbnail-like size though. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: OK, if you say so. Seems like a waste of resources.

Comment: even if Ill make it a little bit smaller, still I`ll have the same problem. instead of getting 20m heap per 20 pic I`ll get 16m... when youll muiltiplay it still a lot of use memory.. something it my technique isnt right..